# How to forceUpdate in setup in vue3?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

How to forceUpdate in setup in vue3?

When use Options Api, I can use this.$forceUpdate() to forceUpdate.How to do the same in setup function in vue3?

Comment: could you give us an example in which case do you need a forceUpdate? There are also [other ways to re-render a component](https://michaelnthiessen.com/force-re-render/).

Comment: @wittgenstein it was tough reading, but I loved your work on the Tractatus.

Comment: that's a good question, i'm also looking for the answer

Answer (score 4):

```js
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, getCurrentInstance } from "vue";

export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    const { ctx: _this }: any = getCurrentInstance()
    let arr = [1]
    const handleClick = () => {
      arr.push(2)
      _this.$forceUpdate()
    }
    return {
      arr
    };
  },
});
</script>
```

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div>{{arr}}</div>
    <button @click="handleClick">add</button>
  </div>
</template>
```

done

Comment: if instead we did const arr = ref([1], arr would be reactive and the forceUpdate would be unnecessary. This is the reason why the Vue docs warn against using getCurrentInstance - unless you are doing some advanced case, it is nearly always a mistake. https://v3.vuejs.org/api/composition-api.html#getcurrentinstance